# IMPORTXML find path containing text, return string

Tags: xml, parsing, google-sheets, import

***objective - search the GPS map on this page and extract coordinates of player***

purpose to create a tracker that will periodically record location of player to google sheets

https://test2.dfprofiler.com/profile/view/13369005

---

**full map**          /html/body/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody

**row**         /html/body/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]

**square**      /html/body/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]

---

setup is full grid map>rows>squares (data in squares)

---

each square contains
< td class="coord x1001 y981" title="">

---

**I want to search all squares for one that contains "playerlocation", then return that string**

< td class="coord x1054 y987 secronomBunker playerlocation" title="" >< /td >

---

next step is to extract only the "**x#### y####**" coordinates but im good to go after i can figure out how to use "contains" right

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTDATA(A1)), 
 "where Col1 contains 'secronomBunker'", ), "(x\d+ y\d+)")
```

[image]

Comment: does xpath work by click path or something?
inspecting element stlll shows the data for GPS when on first tab
so i don't understand why its not possible. how could i accomplish what i need?

i just need to search for that string containing playerlocation

Comment: @DatGuy answer updated

Comment: this works, i was trying to search by "playerlocation" though, secronom bunker is a fixed location

what column is player location in? i cant seem to edit that function quite so simply

Comment: @DatGuy I am not very familiar with the dataset but you can check if it can be targetted if you run: `=QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTDATA(A1)), 
 "where Col1 is not null", )` - its basically the full source code that can be scrapped

Comment: seems like its unable to be scraped. but thanks for the troubleshooter. unsure why "playerlocation" wont show up :/